# codeigniter where with result not working

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, activerecord

```
$this->select("unm")->from("user")->where(array("age"=>20))->result();
```

not working, even any query including `where`.

Not able to use, `result()`, `row()` etc.

```
$rowSet=$this->select("unm")->from("user")->where(array("age"=>20));
$rowSet->result();
```

also not working

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysql_driver::result() in C:\xampp\htdocs\ci\application\models\testModel.php on line 24
```

Answer (score 2):

You didn't executed the query. Try with

```
$rowSet=$this->select("unm")
->from("user")
->where(array("age"=>20));
$rowSet = $this->db->get();   // this was missing
$query->result();
```

For [Reference](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#select)

Comment: thank you, it is working, not expecting that much fast reply ,

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a function like this?

```
public function getDataByID($id) {
    $this->db->select ( '*' );
    $this->db->from ( 'item' );
    $this->db->where ( 'id', $id );

    $query = $this->db->get ();
    $row = $query->first_row ();
    return $row;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

$where_array = array("age"=>20);

```
$result = $this->db->select('unm')
         ->from()
         ->where($where_array)
         ->get()->result();
```

print_r($result);  gives you output in the following form

array([0]=>stdobj(),[1]=>stdobj().....)